# Is there a way to access spell checker of the client machine word application from a web page hosted on a server?

Tags: javascript

There is a text area on a jsp page and if the end user types some text in the text area and clicks on a button, the spell checker in the word application(present in the client's machine) should be invoked and allow the users to choose the suggestions for misspelled words. I would like to do it only in IE browser with use of ActiveXObject. Is there a way to achieve this with HTML/JavaScript/JSP only?

Answer (score 1):

No; that's totally impossible.

Plus, modern browsers already have spell check built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to access the spellchecker in the machine, rather you would need to implement your own or get a service that does so for webpages.(For instance you could call http://orangoo.com/spellcheck/ and get a quote on a service for your site)

Also, it would be from the client's interest to spellcheck so it is not really a requirement for you as a developer/webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

It would take a plug-in written for this that was installed into the local user's browser and had permission to execute code on the local machine.  You could write an ActiveX control that could do this in IE.

If you're looking to do it with HTML/JavaScript/JSP only, you cannot.  For security reasons, you cannot run local code that it outside the browser using those browser technologies.

Comment: Isn't that a security threat? Why would someone install his spellchecker when many are already settled down and available?

Comment: Yes, many ActiveX plugins are security threats.  That's why the technology has not been standardized and is MS-only.  It is possible though to write a safe ActiveX plugin that has a narrow mission if it is done properly.  I would not recommend it in this case because there are likely better ways to do spell checking either using the spell checker built-in to browsers or by using ajax to run the spell check on the server.